# Is there a way of easily identifying which mesh face a UV face corresponds to?

Tags: uv

Is there any simple way of telling which UV face corresponds to which 3D model face?

I created a room (in V 2.71) with a doorway and a window out of a hollowed cube and generated a UV mapping for it with "Smart UV project" but it is not obvious to me how to tell which face is, say, the floor or the left face of the door frame. I can highlight them in the main window to see which face gets highlighted in the UV window, but that's laborious and confusing.

And if my model gets a little more complicated, say I had more rooms and interior doorways, I know I'll end up with lots of tiny thin rectangles on the UV map often placed in really weird locations that don't correspond to the floorplan. Telling which is which will be really hard.

How is this done on complicated models?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable the "keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync" button, in the UV editor[image]

In Blender 3.4+ the button is in the top left of the UV editor.

[image: screenshot of blender interface]