# Rearrange uv where i want

Tags: texturing, uv

i would like to know how to rearrange uv maps to where i want, without messing vertices. For example putting a couple UV on top of e.a other because they have the same texture. Im having a problem doing that because when i try to grab, other vertices come as well.

Comment: maybe this helps? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33852/is-there-a-way-of-easily-identifying-which-mesh-face-a-uv-face-corresponds-to/33853#33853

Comment: Is proprtional editing turned on ? (`Shift`+`Tab`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure proportional editing is disabled, then enable **Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync** and enable Face Selection mode.

Then you can select the faces and rearrange them as you want.

[image]