# Is there a way to highlight a face in the 3D viewport if you have its UV selected?

Tags: uv

So I know if you have a face selected in the 3D Viewport, its UV will pop up in the UV editor. What I want to know is, is there a way to highlight a face in the 3D viewport if you have its corresponding UV selected in the UV editor? Sometimes it's hard to tell where exactly the face of the UV is if it's small or if you have a lot of similarly shaped polygons/uv islands.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33852/is-there-a-way-of-easily-identifying-which-mesh-face-a-uv-face-corresponds-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to enable the *Sync* button here:

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you! That's really helpful. It almost feels like that should be enabled by default. It makes adjusting UVs way easier, at least for me.